# Extend range of rc522 RFID reader on Raspberry Pi to 0.5m

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, rfid, mifare

I'm trying to find a cheap way to get a RFID reading at about 0.3m-0.5m. I currently have a Raspberry Pi 3, and a rc522 RFID reader (code in python).

I can't seem to get a consistent estimate of the max range of this unit. I've heard that you can change it's config or increase the power to get better range, but no proof or clear instructions on whether that will actually work.

I also thought I could possibly build a bigger antenna, but also can't find instructions for that or ranges that will get me (if possible, please send instructions).

I've read that UHF readers will get me there, but their super expensive, and way overkill for my project (unless I can cheaply build my own UHF reader).

Has anyone had the same problem, and found a solution. Not sure if this is the right place to post this. I've not, sugesstions are welcome.

Comment: This question suits better for http://electronics.stackexchange.com/
Also in [this](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=199983) thread similar problems discussed.

Comment: Thanks, I've been though the mentioned thread, but they only speak of ranges at about 10cm, but other blogs say this module can go up to 1m. Will also try electronics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

Getting such a range with the RC522 is impossible, just because the RC522 uses the ISO14443A standard which is designed forshort range <10cm while high speeds 106kbps. As you said UHF is a solution but extremely expensive and made for professionnals. The 2 other solutions are
- ISO 15693 RFIDs. It's a long range protocol operating at 13.56MHz. This protocol supports long range with the appropriate reader and antenna. However, most of the cheap ISO15693 readers can't read tags more than 10cm and they often need to be connected to a PC. Such systems are used in public libraries and skipasses.
- long range 125khz rfid. I don't know much about that but it would be possible to buy or make a long range reader

I highly recommand you to search for ISO 14443 A, ISO 15693 and 125khz rfid on Google and Wikipedia